# Displaying parent and their child of one level wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show website links at footer of my website in wordpress. I want fetch all pages and their sub pages of one depth.

Then I want to display them in three columns like if there are total 8 pages then these should be displayed 3-3-2 in first-second-third column. new to wordpress.

can any body please help

I tried this but dont know how i can align them in 3-3-2

```
     <?php
  $counter = 0;
     $parent_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *  FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = '0' AND ID <> 2 AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT'); ?>
  <?php if ( $parent_pages ) : foreach ( $parent_pages as $pageParent ) : setup_postdata( $pageParent ); ?>
  <?php $counter++; ?>
    <div class="linkSection">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($pageParent->ID); ?>"><?php echo $pageParent->post_title; ?></a></a> </li>
       <?php  
          $child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *  FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = '".$pageParent->ID."' AND ID <> 2 AND post_type = 'page' 
          ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT'); ?>
         <?php if ( $child_pages ) : foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) : setup_postdata( $pageChild ); ?>
          <li><a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>"><?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?></a></a> </li>
         <?php endforeach; endif; ?>



      </ul>
  </div>
  <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$counter = 0;
$cnt = 0;
$parent_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *  FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = '0' AND ID <> 2 AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT'); ?>
<?php if ( $parent_pages ) : foreach ( $parent_pages as $pageParent ) : setup_postdata( $pageParent ); ?>
<?php $counter++; ?>
<div class="linkSection">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($pageParent->ID); ?>"><?php echo $pageParent->post_title; ?></a></a> </li>
            <?php  
            $child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("
                SELECT *  
                FROM $wpdb->posts 
                WHERE post_parent = '".$pageParent->ID."' 
                      AND ID <> 2 
                      AND post_type = 'page' 
                ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT'); 

                // define prefix and postdix for columns (3 in a row display)
                $pre = '<div class="row_3">';
                $pos = '</div>';

                if ( $child_pages )
                {
                    foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) 
                    {
                        setup_postdata( $pageChild ); 
                        echo (($cnt%3==0 || $cnt==0) ? $pre:'').
                              '<li>
                                <a href=".'get_permalink($pageChild->ID).'">'.$pageChild->post_title.'</a>
                              </li>'
                            .(($cnt%3==0 || $cnt==0) ? $pos:'');
                        $cnt++;
                    }
                    $cnt = 0;
                }
            ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

So what i did? First, i reformat your code. Yes, i know, that WP uses that style, but it is bad readable for me. Than I added prefix\postfix for list of links. And in-loop counter.

How it works: in loop we count every iteration with `$cnt++;`. In every print we check if it is third row or not if yes - we add prefix and postfix to our line.

Now u can adjust css-styles for "row_3" to make it 3-in-row display.